# Increase PDA size after deployment

Tags: anchor, pda, account-data

I read somewhere some time ago that Solana now provides feature to increase the PDA size post deployment. For example, let's assume that I deploy a PDA with a capacity to hold 10 Publickeys and later I realize that I want it to hold 20 Publickeys then I can do it even after deployment which was not possible earlier. My questions are:

a) Is it correct? Or am I dreaming of reading it somewhere?

b) Can you direct me to the source so that I can use this in my code?

Many Thanks for your help.

Comment: https://dev.to/jacobcreech/how-to-change-account-size-on-solana-55b4

https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/7367/anchor-realloc-pda